# Find words in multiple files starting with a specific set of characters and replace the whole word with another word

Tags: java

I need to read through multiple files and check for all occurrences of words that start with a specific pattern and replace it in all the files with another word. For example, I need to find all words beginning with 'Hello' in a set of files which may contain words like 'Hellotoall' and then I want the word to be replaced with 'Greetings', just an example. I have tried:

```
content = content.replaceAll("/Hello(\\w)+/g", "Greetings");
```

This code results in : `Greetingstoall`, but I want the whole word to be replaced with 'Greetings', i.e. if the file has a line:
`Today i say Hellotoall present here`.  After replacement the line should be like: `Today i say Greetings present here`.

How can I achieve such a requirement with a better regex.

Comment: Where did you get those `/` and `/g` from? Looks like you get them from `sed` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just `"Hello(\\w)*"`.

Comment: this doesn't match `Hello`, not sure is this is intended behavior by the OP

Comment: Fixed that. Just use `*` instead of `+`

Comment: @user16320675 No. I just copypasted it from original code.

Answer (score 0):

isn't the output `Greetingsoall`? The match would be `Hellot` - so first thing is that you may want to replace `+` with `*`

As talex pointed out, there is sed syntax mixed in, which doesn't work with Java.

```
content.replaceAll("Hello\w*", "Greetings")
```